# Sincere to or Sincerity to

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

He is **sincere to** his religious belief

His **sincerity to** the religious belief

I think the first one is more common in use.

My question is, the second one is grammatical? Can i use sincerity with "to"?

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second one is not a complete sentence, since there is no verb.

Comment: Yes I know, but my question is, "sincerity to" in the sentence is grammatical?. Because I find very less results for "sincerity to" vs "sincerity of".

Comment: I think either is fine and commonly used. If you see a problem could you be more specific?

Comment: Actually the first one is incorrect.  The second is fine.  Consider "He is sincere in his religious belief" instead.

Comment: @farnsy the first one sounds fine to me tbh. I've heard that said many times.

Comment: @bobbin Which side of the Atlantic are you on? Could be one of those things that differs depending on your continent.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds off to me. It's much more common to use "in", "regarding", or possibly "on". It could also take "of" if it were reword to "The sincerity of his religious belief".

Answer (score 0):

The second form is fine. “His sincerity to the faith is unwavering.” It feels a bit odd to say one is sincere to a faith though, since a faith is an abstract, impersonal noun.

I think this example would be better served with “devotion:” “His devotion to the faith is unwavering.” This example is grammatically without fault, and devotion and faith are frequently paired together.

But I don’t think I’m exactly answering your question?